# microtime in second with 2 decimals

Tags: php, microtime

I try calculate time of an act in second with 2 decimals.

```
protected function microtimeFormat($data)
    {
        $duration = microtime(true) - $data;
        $hours = (int)($duration/60/60);
        $minutes = (int)($duration/60)-$hours*60;
        return $seconds = $duration-$hours*60*60-$minutes*60;

    }
```

this method get start time as $data...and get back it an int second

for example it return 2second.

I try get second with 2 decimals ...

```
protected function microtimeFormat($data,$format=null,$lng=null)
    {
        $duration = microtime(true) - $data;
        $hours = (float)($duration/60/60);
        $minutes = (float)($duration/60)-$hours*60;
        $seconds = $duration-$hours*60*60-$minutes*60;
        return number_format((float)$seconds, 2, '.', '');
    }
```

but it return me 0.00 for short time

Comment: use PHP's round function: http://php.net/manual/en/function.round.php

Comment: I've tried your code and received 2.0001289844513 and 2.00 - these are seconds and result of number_format

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think your issue comes from the `(float)` conversion to `$hours` and `$minutes`. When you do so you don't save the decimal part of each so your calculation of `$seconds` always give 0. Convert to `int` so you actually save in `$hours` and `$minutes` the actual number of seconds they each represent. And the remainder goes to `$seconds`.

```
protected function microtimeFormat($data,$format=null,$lng=null)
{
    $duration = microtime(true) - $data;
    $hours = (int)($duration/60/60);
    $minutes = (int)($duration/60)-$hours*60;
    $seconds = $duration-$hours*60*60-$minutes*60;
    return number_format((float)$seconds, 2, '.', '');
}

$start = microtime(TRUE);
sleep(1);
$delay = $this->microtimeFormat($start);
var_dump($delay);
```

This gives me:

```
string(4) "1.01"
```

Comment: if i do `sleep(70);` i get result: `string(5) "10.00"`

Comment: I'm new to php, not new to programming. Although your code just proved very useful to me, this kind of code is the reasons people talk bad about PHP. thanks anyway

Answer (score 0):

I use this form to generate a time in seconds, eg **1.20**

```
$start = microtime(true);
for ($i=0; $i < 10000000; $i++) { 
    # code...
}
$end = microtime(true);

echo "<br>" . $time = number_format(($end - $start), 2);
// We get this: 1.20
```

**An example comparing the performance of 2 functions of PHP:**

```
define( 'NUM_TESTS', 1000000);

$start = microtime(true);

for( $i = 0; $i < NUM_TESTS; $i++)
{
    mt_rand();
}

$end = microtime(true) - $start;
echo 'mt_rand: ' . number_format(($end), 2) . "\n";

$start = microtime(true);

for( $i = 0; $i < NUM_TESTS; $i++)
{
    uniqid();
}

$end = microtime(true) - $start;
echo 'uniqid: ' . number_format(($end), 2) . "\n";
// We get this: mt_rand: 0.12 uniqid: 2.06
```